# What's the difference between all of the different versions of Visual Studio Express?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

please move this to another SE site if it's inappropriate. I just figure it's about programming and it's got a specific answer.

My question is, I'm trying to download to VS2010 Express for home use. It's got 4 versions. C#, VB.NET, C++ and Web Developer.

What is web developer for? And what programming language does it cater to? And does that mean you can't create ASP.NET web apps in the other versions?

Answer (score 1):

1. What is web developer for? For developing web application you have to use Web Developer Express version. This is only one version which allow you to create web site on your hard disk and using embedded in Visual Studio web server or on IIS web server that is possible exists on your local machine. If you haven't it then you can use only embedded in Visual Studio web server.
2. What programming language does it cater to? It's enough to have skills in c# or vb.net, due to the fact that other language hasn't specified for such version of Visual Studio :). So, you have only two option for such version: c# (more prefereble in my opinion) or VB.NET.
3. Does that mean you can't create ASP.NET web apps in the other versions? Yes, you can't create your web site with expression version of Visual Studio in other versions, only ASP.NET 4 and Framework 4 for Visual Studio 2010 and ASP.NET 2 and Framework 3.5 for Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: sorry i don't really understand what you are trying to say

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding, in edited version i have tried to explain more obviously

Comment: And the other three version mentioned in the question are to develop windows (non-web) applications with different languages.  So to answer the unasked question, which version should you download?  1) If you are doing web development download the Web Developer. 2) If you are doing non web, download one of the other three in your preferred language.

Comment: @apros feel free to add my comment to your answer if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the sources for comparison - https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs.aspx

In general, the ranking is Ultimate -> Premium -> Pro -> Express for highest to lowest.

Comment: This doesn't really help answer the question as he is looking at the different version of Express rather than at the difference between express and the other products.